# jquery add and remove input using bind

Tags: jquery

I would like to add only two rows. I have 2 issues with below code.

1. It is keep adding more than two rows.
2. When i try to remove, it is not removing the selected record.

http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/14/Here is DEMO

```
$('#addProfile').bind('click', function() {

            if($('#container').find('#removeProfile').length < 2) {

                var len = $('#container').find('#removeProfile').length;
                //alert(len);
                var index = len+1;

                $('#container').append('<div>&nbsp;</div><div class ="form-group-inline"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Profile Number</label><div class="col-sm-3"><input  class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="profileNumber" id="profileNumber" /></div><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Amount</label><div class="col-sm-3"><input  class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" /></div><div class="col-sm-2"><button type="button" id="removeProfile" class="btn btn-success">RemoveProfile</button></div></div>');


            }else{

                bootbox.alert("You cannot add more than two profiles!", function() {});

            }
        })
 });

  $('body').on('click', '#removeProfile', function() {
if($('#container').find('#removeProfile').length > 0) {            
    $(this).parent().remove();

 }
})
```

I am able to add record in my workspace, but same code is not working in fiddle. I am hoping somecan help me to first make it work in fiddle then take a look at the issues i have. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your HTML looks like but seeing your code makes me think it is invalid because you can't have more than one element with ID **removeProfile**. That is also your problem. `.length` will always return 1 when trying to get the length of elements with the same ID.

Comment: I have only one id with the "removeProfile". whic is in container append code above.

Comment: No, you are appending a new one when you click.

Comment: when i am dynamically adding elements like this what else i can use for finding the legnth ?

Comment: Each time you append the HTML to the container div, you create a new element with id of `removeProfile`.  I would suggest you switch it to a class and use `on()` to determine which profile container has been clicked.

Comment: I am still waiting for the solution. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$('#container').find('#removeProfile').length`, you will always get 0 or 1, not more.
You can't have the same ID twice anyway. Remove the ID or make it unique.   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534704(v=vs.85).aspx).

Instead you can use `.form-group-inline` to check how many you have.
So do :

```
if($('#container .form-group-inline').length < 2) { .... }
```

And for the remove part, you are adding a click handler to an element with selector `name=removeProfile`. You don't have any. Rather do :

```
$('body').on('click', '.form-group-inline .btn-success', function() { 
    if($('#container .form-group-inline').length > 0) {            
        $(this).parents('.form-group-inline').remove();
    }
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Iwill try this, meanwhile i have updated my original post using id instead of name. Will that work for removing part ?

Comment: I tried this. Adding part is working. It is able to count and alerting. But remove part is still not working.

Comment: It works the same as your code, only with a different selector. Maybe you need to remove the parent of the parent.. ill update the answer.

Comment: Have you had a chnace to update the answer ? Thnak you!